# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta por rango de fechas y horas?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Necesito hacer una consulta por rango de fechas y horas.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VistaAHUMA00016 
WHERE (FechaDate BETWEEN '2018-05-28' AND '2018-06-05') 
AND (HoraTime BETWEEN '09:14' AND '14:00')
```

Necesito saber de qué manera puedo hacer que la consulta tome los datos de todos los días desde la fecha 2018-05-28 a partir de las 09:14 hasta la fecha 2018-06-05 terminando a las 14:00 -> aquí es donde debería terminar la consulta.

Esta es la estructura de los campos en la tabla:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir:

- FechaDate (date, NULL)
- HoraTime (time(7), NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba está solución

```
SELECT * FROM VistaAHUMA00016 WHERE ( (FechaDate = '2018-05-28' AND HoraTime >='09:14') OR (FechaDate > '2018-05-28' and FechaDate < '2018-06-05') or (FechaDate = '2018-06-05' AND HoraTime <='14:00') )
```

Comment: gracias amigo! esta consulta si me funciono a la perfección!

Answer (score 2):

prueba de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    VistaAHUMA00016 
WHERE
    (
        (FechaDate  >= '2018-05-28' AND HoraTime >='09:14')
        AND
        (FechaDate <= '2018-06-05' AND HoraTime <='14:00')
    )
```

Evaluamos en la primer condicion que la fecha sea mayor a la indicada asi como la hora y en la segunda igual pero menor a la fecha y menor a la hora, espero te funcione, saludos.

Comment: jajajaja exactamente hice esa consulta ayer @Erick Soto y ni así logre que me trajera los datos como lo requieren :(

Comment: corrección bro, si funciona perfectamente! no me fije bien y no tengo mas datos después de las 14:00 horas en ese rango de fechas jajaja

Comment: corrección 2, hice la prueba sobre un rango de fechas en las cuales una fecha si tiene hasta las 15:00 horas, pero solo muestra hasta un rango de las 14:00 horas, luego de eso no se me ocurrió nada mas :(

Comment: mm creo que solo deberias cambiar la HoraTime <= '15:00' .... , o lo que en realidad necesitas es ver los registros de ese rango de fechas pero solo aquellos que tienen la hora entre las 09:14 y las 14:00 ?

Comment: no bro, lo que necesito es que por ejemplo si hago una consulta hoy 31 de agosto del 2018 a las 09:00 am hasta el 05 de septiembre del 2018 hasta las 22:00 pm me traiga todos los registros a partir de la primera fecha y hora hasta la fecha final final y hora :(

Comment: Esta muy raro que no te arroje los datos con la consulta que te agregue solo cambiando los parametros de las fechas y horas, de hecho la consulta que tu publicaste tambien es correcta y deberia arrojarte datos, claro si es que existen entre ese inter de fechas y horas.

Comment: si bro, aunque acabo de probar la consulta del compañero de arriba y funciono a la perfección! gracias por tu ayuda bro!

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que tener la fecha y hora en un mismo campo, seria algo asi

```
SELECT * 
FROM VistaAHUMA00016 
WHERE (FechaDate BETWEEN '2018-05-28 09:14' AND '2018-06-05 14:00')
```

La otra forma seria que concatenaras la fecha y la hora en nuevo "campo" y hacer la comparacion sobre este campo.

Comment: hola @dbamex gracias por tu ayuda, probé la consulta, pero sin embargo no me genera los datos correctos, se me olvido mencionar que tanto la fecha como la hora están en campos diferentes, como tal la fecha esta en formato date y la hora en time, la base de datos no se puede alterar ya que así es como la usan actualmente :(

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo en que primero debes juntar fecha y hora en un solo campo podrias intentar haciendo la siguiente consulta, en la condicion `where` se convierte a `datetime` tu campo `fechadate` y se suma tu campo `time`, el resto lo hace el `between` considerando todos los registros a partir del '2018-05-28 09:14:00 hasta la fecha final '2018-06-05 14:00:00'.

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM
   VistaAHUMA00016 
WHERE
   (cast(FechaDate as datetime) + horatime) BETWEEN '2018-05-28 09:14:00' AND '2018-06-05 14:00:00'
```